# What happens if I leave a turned off laptop under direct sunlight for several hours?

Tags: laptop

What likely happens if I leave a laptop switched off and closed under direct sunlight for several hours? Which damage will it likely incur? What fatal consequences are likely and how likely are they? What risks are there that are not typically expected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The battery most likely will lose capacity. Capacity loss for Li-Ion batteries strongly depends on the temperature and raising it that much will probably have some effect. Apart from that, I doubt much will happen you'd notice.

Comment: Also, it will probably get a nasty sun burn and will be very, very thirsty. ;)

Comment: @Joey, Is losing capacity a temporary problem or an irreversible one?

Comment: @Pacerier: Permanent.