# Keep laptop in hot car indefinitely

Tags: laptop, cooling

I'd like to know if there's a good way to store a laptop (or other personal electronics) in a hot car long-term. For example, if I want to always just keep a Chromebook with a hotspot in my trunk, just in case I find myself in a situation where I need it - ideally I'd like it to even stay cool enough where I can use it right away without waiting for it to cool down once I bring it inside.

I'm in Phoenix, where the ridiculously long summer gets into the high 110s F, occasionally 120, which means a car gets much hotter than that. The inside gets to 160+, but I don't think the trunk does - but 120 wouldn't surprise me.

I've seen insulated laptop bags, pizza bags, thermal food coolers, etc., but I don't know if any of these would help long-term, or if they would just work for a day or two. Ideally, I'd like to just throw it in the trunk and forget about it until I need it, maybe weeks or months at a time.

**EDIT** I have seen questions related to leaving a laptop in a car for a short time, but I'm talking more about long-term. I know I absolutely shouldn't leave it unprotected for this long, so ideally I was hoping for a "XYZ thermos product will keep your laptop cool in a trunk for a week" answer, but it's looking unlikely based on the responses so far.

Comment: This question is not a real good fit for the Q&A format and [topic guidelines](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) of Super User because answers would be opinion based. Questions here should be practical, answerable questions related to a problem you actually face. With that being said, I'd suggest doing some research. Conduct a temperature study of your trunk, insulated container in your trunk, etc. When you know the actual temps, you can determine if the max operating temperature of a laptop (outlined in it's specs) will be exceeded.

Comment: Insulated is not going to beat ambient temperatures of 110+ for 8+ hours at a time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will hot weather break my laptop?](http://superuser.com/questions/429154/will-hot-weather-break-my-laptop)

Answer (score 3):

The most heat-sensitive element of a laptop is the battery. Li-ion and Li-po batteries are not supposed to get hotter than 45 °C (113 F), as per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_battery#Extreme_temperatures). Above 60 °C (or 140 F), irreversible chemical reactions start inside the battery, quickly reducing its lifespan.

High temperature also contributes to thermal decay of all materials, although at a slower rate. Most commercial-grade electronic components are rated for an operation temperature of at least 70 C, and I doubt your thunk gets that hot. BTW, electronics in your car should be rated "industrial" and support operating temperatures up to 80 - 90 °C or so.

I'm not sure if keeping the laptop without battery makes any sense to you, but that's what I would suggest. Although in half a year or so there probably will be little difference, since the battery will hit the end of life because of heat.